# Exponential distribution/ probability

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Suppose the average number of days between car accidents at a specific intersection is 64 days, and follows an exponential distribution

a) what is the probability that there will be there will be three months between accidents (assume 30-day months)

P(time between accidents=90days)

$\int_1^{90} λe^{- λT} dT = [-e^{- λT}]_1^{90}$

$-e^{-(64)(90)} = 0$ and $-e^{-(64)(1)} = -1.604X10^{-28 } $

$= 1.604X10^{-28}$

b) if an accident occurs at the beginning of a 30 day month, calculate the probability that another accident will occur in the same month

c) what is the variance of the times between accidents?

I'm not sure if I did a) right because for some reason i keep getting the same answer for b) even if i plug in a different number. Please help

Comment: Two comments: Firstly, the integral should start at zero rather than 1. Second, there seems to be a units issue. Double check whether $\lambda$ should be a time or a rate.

Comment: wouldn't lambda be 64 days, the average number of days between car accidents at a specific intersection.

Comment: and why would it start at 0 there is no 0th day, the calendar starts at 1

Comment: Well, there are only 89 days between day 1 and day 90. Also if something happens one day from now, I count the time from right now until 24 hours from now. Also, $\lambda$ is not 64 days. $\lambda$ is the rate at which car accidents happen. The last bit is just because that's how the exponential distribution is defined.

Comment: $\lambda = 1/64$

Comment: It is vital to understand the parameterization of the exponential distribution: the parameter is the inverse of the mean.

Comment: okay thanks that works

Comment: so then for b) would you do the same thing from a) just use 30 instead of 90?